# Last message of each course

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables (users, courses, messages) and I want to get the last message for each course of a specific user.

users table (id, username, password, phone_number, ...)
courses table (id, name, type, author_id, ...)
messages table (id, course_id, from, date_created)

messages table includes phone number of user instead of user id so its connection is:

WHERE M.`from` = (SELECT U.phone_number FROM user U WHERE id=244)

Comment: Do you have some sort of time stamp on the messages? If you sort descending by that time stamp and limit the output to three records.

Comment: I have timestamps but I depend on the Whatsapp date received